# C# HttpWebResponse.GetResponse() hangs when I put it in a method

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I want to search on a website for 4 digit numbers and extract a link on the page, which contains this number.
The following code works fine:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> urls = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
for (int index = 3000; index < 4000; index++) {
    string url = "http://www.myurl.com/page?q=" + index.ToString();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = null;

        if (response.CharacterSet == null) {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        } else {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
        }

        string itemurl = "";
        while (!readStream.EndOfStream) {
            string ln = readStream.ReadLine();
            int start = ln.IndexOf("https://www.myurl.com/" + index.ToString());
            if (start > -1) {
                int stop = ln.IndexOf(".htm\"", start) + 4;
                itemurl = ln.Substring(start, stop - start);
                Console.Write(index + ", ");
                urls.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(index, itemurl));
                break;
            }
        }
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
    }
}
```

However, if I put the checking part (everything in the loop) into a method, which returns the url:

```
string GetUrl(int index) {
..
        //urls.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(index, itemurl)); is replaced by:
        return itemurl;
..
    return "";
}
```

Then I call the method in the loop:

```
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> urls = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    for (int index = 3000; index < 4000; index++) {
        string itemurl = GetUrl(index);
        if(itemurl != "") urls.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(index, itemurl));
    }
```

The program will hang exactly after 2 urls are found and I can't see any reason why this is happening. The hang will happen at `request.GetResponse();`
I tried to set the Timeout to 500 ms, catch the exception and retry a bit later, but I still won't get a response.
I can also search other numbers and the result is the same. It will hang after two urls are found. I tried to switch between Release or Debug, between .NET 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.6 and the result is the same. I'm running Windows 10, but I also tried it on a remote computer running 8.1 and an XP VM and got the same.

If I don't put it in a separate method, then it checks 1000 numbers in less than a minute.

I started to get really upset by this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of struggling, I found what's causing the problem, so I'll share the solution.

The problem was, that I didn't call the `response.Close()` method when I returned an url, so it was still using the resources. Calling this method before returning solved the problem.
Another solution is to put the code into a using block, like:

```
using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()){
..
}
```